# Class not found after installing with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I followed the instructions to install this package:

https://github.com/embedly/embedly-php#installing

In my code I did:

```
$api = new Embedly\Embedly(array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0)'));

$objs = $api->oembed('http://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-37077172?ns_mchannel=social&ns_campaign=bbc_breaking&ns_source=twitter&ns_linkname=news_central');

print_r($objs);
```

But I get this error:

> Class 'Embedly\Embedly' not found

What am I missing? Do I have to put something in the provider/alias? If so, I don't know what. I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: you have the `require_once` ??

Comment: Isn't the point of composer to not have to use `require`? Can I not just refer to it somehow by its alias?

Comment: Check your vendor directory, do you see the package installed? Also try doing `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: When you say "in my code I did", which file?

Comment: @user6703162, having to only require a single autoloader is one benefit of using Composer, but I wouldn't say it's "the point". The main benefit is that it takes care of installing your dependencies (and _their_ dependencies, recursively).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you just followed README, which was missing line for composer.
I've added that in [PR](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-php/pull/24/files).

To explain that, Composer handles all your autoloading and dependencies. To enable that explicitly, you need to include it's autoload file, where all this happens.

Just begin your `index.php` (or container) file with:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// your code
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add another '\' at the beginning like this:

`$api = new \Embedly\Embedly(...) ;`

Comment: This would not help, as there is no namespace above